# Extremely large amount of data in jos_session

Tags: performance, session, joomla, virtuemart

I noticed yesterday that my joomla/virtuemart site was becoming very slow.

I contacted the hosting provider and they told me about queries to jos_session.
I looked in phpmyadmin at the table jos_session and noticed that the data field for each session id had an insane amount of lines. A total of 157.080 characters to be exact.

At the time when this came up I was uploading products to virtuemart with csvimproved. Everything had been smooth and I had around 3000 product on the site but now when I have around 10.000 products everything is very slow.

I don't know where this data in jos_session is coming from and I'm not certain that it's related to these products.

Do you guys have any idea what is happening or how I could find out?

Thanks

Comment: I am also seeing in debug mode that a browse page which contains 50 products with images and price logs around 1200 mysql queries. That is way way too much. How can I find out where those queries are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the session in a public page, you can use this in `index.php`:

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site',array('session'=>false));
```